# How to make the user see his own data after registration?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

For example, I've got MySQL table with all users data

[image]

How to make after user sign in, he sees his own username?

I've tried this:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while (rs.next()) {
  String name = rs.getString(1);
  System.out.println("username : " + name);
}
```

But it just shows all usernames in MySQL table.

Comment: What are the contents of **query** string?

Comment: `String query = "select username from users";`

Comment: Could you please specify , what user provide for login ?

Comment: You should also not store passwords in cleartext. Store a salted hash, with a unique salt per User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not filter the rows of the table.
Use a `WHERE` clause:

```
String query = "select username from users where username = ?";
stmt.setString(1, user); 
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("username : " + name);
} else {
    System.out.println("No user : " + user);
}
```

The `?` placeholder will be replaced by the value of the variable `user` properly quoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "select username from users";
```

to

```
String query = "select username from users where username = '"+user+"' ";
```

To avoid sql injections, it is advisable to use a PreparedStament. Check this link for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: Please don't recommend solutions that are vulnerable to SQL injection. You 'soften' this by providing a link to the `PreparedStatement` documentation, but that link doesn't provide a clear description of what SQL injection is and why it is dangerous. Instead of suggesting solutions that have security vulnerabilities, in the future please provide solutions that are more secure (like the one provided by forpas).